# Second derivative approximation at the endpoint of a bounded function

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences

I have a function defined on [a, b] and trying to approximate its second derivative using finite differences method. The centered finite difference formula works for interior points, but not for $x=b$. For $f''(b)$, it needs $f(b+h)$ which is not defined.

How could I tackle the problem  at $x=b$? Is there a numerical way to approximate it by all means?

Comment: Approximate something that you know doesn't exist? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Conifold Sorry for being unclear, basically I'm trying to approximate the second derivative for a function f(x) defined on [a,b] at point x=b. If using the finite differences method, then I'll need f(b+h) which is not defined. How could I tackle the problem in this case? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @CareBear Thanks for help! Do you mean the Dirichlet boundary condition? f(b) is indeed known, and how could I make use of it? Could you elaborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: One way is to use a backward finite difference on the boundary, a few such things are [listed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient#Forward_and_backward_finite_difference). But you may also want to consider the wider context: are you sure you **need** $f''(b)$? Are you solving some PDE?

Comment: @CareBear The backward finite difference would give the second derivative at some point smaller than b which is somewhat inaccurate and that's the last choice I guess. I was wondering if there is some other alternative method to apply here? The question is actually from an optimization problem of some log-Likelihood function.

Comment: The straightforward formula $u''(b)\approx h^{-2}(u(b)-2u(b-h)+u(b-2h))$ is indeed somewhat inaccurate, being just the centered second derivative at $b-h$. But the more sophisticated $u''(b)\approx h^{-2}(2u(b)-5u(b-h)+4u(b-2h)-u(b-3h))$ is of the second order of accuracy, same as the centered formula you are using at the interior points.